# How to display a .docx file in iframe

Tags: html, reactjs, iframe

Currently, I need to display a word document with iframe but don't know how to make It work.
My source path which is a Blob URL is:

```
var filePath = "blob:http://localhost:8080/b73d1841-5a54-416f-8931-7d5702a4dc7e"
```

When I put it into an iframe:

```
<iframe id="fileViewer" src={filePath}></iframe>
```

It doesn't appear anything and return a warning:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type 
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document: 
"blob:http://localhost:8080/....".
```

But If I use the same code with other type like pdf, It will work perfectly.
Can someone pointout what I am missing ?